# Equivalencity of $xI-A$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be two matrices over $\mathbb Q[x]$. What is the relation be the the conditions that (1) $\det(xI-A) = \det (xI-B)$ and that (2) $A$ and $B$ are equivalent, that is, there exists invertible matrices $P$ and $Q$ over $\mathbb Q[x]$ such that $A = PBQ$.

Do these two conditions imply each other? If so, what is a proof? If one does not imply the other, why not?

Comment: This looks interesting, but it would be nice if you could add some [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) to your question. For example, what you think of the problem, how you've encountered it, what you've tried, where you got stuck...

Comment: What do you know about equivalent matrices? For example, can you see that two matrices are equivalent if and only if they have the same rank?

Comment: @ZachLangley Are you sure that this would still be true for matrices over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ (which is not a field)?

Comment: @ArnaudD. Ah, no. I am not.

Comment: Similarity implies same rank but the other implication is true in general?

Comment: You know that $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a PID. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form for a similarity condition over PIDs and apply it for $\mathbb{Q}[x][y]$.

Answer (score 1):

No relations.

Example 1. Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 &0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and 
$B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 &1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ They have the same characteristic polynomial ($\det(Ix-A)=\det(Ix-B)=x^2$) but the only matrix equivalent to $A$ is $A$ itself.

---

Example 2.
Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and 
$B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}$
They have different characteristic polynomials but
if $P=\begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and 
$Q=\begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 \\ 0 & 1/2\end{pmatrix}$
then $PBQ=A$.

Answer (score 0):

None of the condition implies the other.
Take B to be the $0$ matrix and A to be the $0$ matrix with a nonzero element in the upper right corner. det(A-xI)=det(B-xI) but there are no invertible matrices P and Q as you require.

For the second condition to imply the first any two invertible matrices would have to have the same  characteristic poly which is absurd