# Equivalence of matrices over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Someone asked a variant of this question recently ([Equivalencity of $xI-A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3039583/equivalencity-of-xi-a)). I ran across a suspiciously similar question today!

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{Q}$.

1. If $\det(xI-A) = \det(xI-B)$, can you say $xI-A$ and $xI-B$ are equivalent over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$? This is false and is answered here ([Does equality of characteristic polynomials guarantee equivalence of matrices?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56673/does-equality-of-characteristic-polynomials-guarantee-equivalence-of-matrices))
2. If $xI-A$ and $xI-B$ are equivalent over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, are $A$ and $B$ similar?

My suspicion is that (2.) is also false. If it were true, then we would have  matrices $P,Q$ over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $xI-A = P(xI-B)Q$. And I am not sure how to reduce matrices over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ to matrices over $\mathbb{Q}$ to get the required similarity relation. Although, this seems to be a slightly stronger statement than $A$ and $B$ have the same characteristic polynomial.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: 2) is true. $A-\lambda$ and $B-\lambda$ being $\lambda$-equivalent is the necessary and sufficient condition for $A,B$ being similar.